# multi model forms in yii

Tags: php, templates, yii, yii-cmodel, yii-chtml

How to create a multi-model form in Yii? I searched the entire documentation of Yii, but got no interesting results. Can some one give me some direction or thoughts about that? Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my expirience i got this solution to work and quickly understandable

You have two models for data you wish collect. Let's say `Person` and `Vehicle`.

### Step 1 : Set up controller for entering form

In your controller create model objects:

```
public function actionCreate() {

  $Person = new Person;
  $Vehicle = new Vehicle;

  //.. see step nr.3

  $this->render('create',array(
        'Person'=>$Person,
        'Vehicle'=>$Vehicle)
  );
}
```

### Step 2 : Write your view file

```
//..define form
echo CHtml::activeTextField($Person,'name');
echo CHtml::activeTextField($Person,'address');
// other fields..

echo CHtml::activeTextField($Vehicle,'type');
echo CHtml::activeTextField($Vehicle,'number');

//..enter other fields and end form
```

put some labels and design in your view ;)

### Step 3 : Write controller `on $_POST` action

and now go back to your controller and write funcionality for POST action

```
if (isset($_POST['Person']) && isset($_POST['Vehicle'])) {
    $Person = $_POST['Person']; //dont forget to sanitize values
    $Vehicle = $_POST['Vehicle']; //dont forget to sanitize values
    /*
        Do $Person->save() and $Vehicle->save() separately
        OR
        use Transaction module to save both (or save none on error) 
        http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#using-transactions
    */
}
else {
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','You must enter both data for Person and Vehicle');
 // or just skip `else` block and put some form error box in the view file
}
```

Comment: I know it can works. But I'm not sure if it's hurts the MVC pattern. Or else wouldn't exists CFormModel. AFAIK it's 1 Model <> 1 Controller <> n Views

Comment: I think it doesnt break anything for the structure. But for more examples i think maybe one more solution would be ok: Create new model which merges data/columns from two models. And now use FormModel in view as one model `CHtml::activeTextField( $MergedModel , 'type');`. But this solution is more confusing and ugly.. hmm

Comment: This is the methodology presented in the yii manual, but imo is clearer to understand, http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/

Answer (score 3):

You can find some examples in these two Yii wiki articles:

- [Yii 1.1: How to use a single form to collect data for two or more models?](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/)
- [Yii 1.1: How to use single form to collect data for two or more models (CActiveForm and Ajax Validation edition)](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/218/how-to-use-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models-cactiveform-and-ajax-validation-edition/).

Answer (score 2):

You don`t need a multi-model. The right use of the MVC pattern requires a Model that reflects your UI.

To solve it, you'll have to use a CFormModel instead of an ActiveRecord to pass the data from View to Controller. Then inside your Controller you`ll parse the model, the CFormModel one, and use the ActiveRecord classes (more than one) to save in database.

[Forms Overview](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.overview) and [Form Model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model) chapters in Yii Definitive Guide contains some details and samples.

Comment: `The right use of the MVC pattern requires a Model that reflects your UI` - whoever taught you this was fatally wrong

Answer (score 1):

**Another suggestions -**

Also we can use **Wizard Behavior**,  It's an extension that simplifies the handling of multi-step forms. In which we can use multi model forms for registration process flow or others.

Demo - http://wizard-behavior.pbm-webdev.co.uk/